# Recommended username and password management plugin for WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, subscription

I have a lot of usernames/passwords from various sites and I would like to use WordPress to store these. I use WP as my daily dashboard and save all my links there. Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: what would the benefit be? Seems like it's just asking for trouble when it gets hacked.

Comment: This is not programming related and is off topic for Stack Overflow. Perhaps try http://wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: lol @jalf WHEN it gets hacked.

Comment: @BandonRandon: I think it's safe to assume that off-the-shelf web software (especially written in PHP) exposed on a public-facing web server *will* eventually get hacked. It's just a matter of when.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [1Password](http://agilewebsolutions.com/onepassword), or use your browser's password storage. Using WordPress for that is just silly, as others have said.

Comment: Major +1 for 1Password, especially with Dropbox syncing across all computers (and iPhones!).